# How to add datagrid column name in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have defined the datagrid as follows

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="100%" height="100%" >
```

In the  part i am trying to get the details from the database and setting the dataProvider for the DataGrid as follows.

```
var arrayContent:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

                for(var i:int=0;i<assetClassDetails.length;i++)
                {
                    var assetClass_:AssetItemClassVO = new AssetItemClassVO();
                    var array:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                    var embeddableLocale:EmbeddableAssetItemClassLocale = new EmbeddableAssetItemClassLocale();
                    var assetClassD_:AssetItemClassLocale = new AssetItemClassLocale(); 
                    assetClass_ = assetClassDetails.getItemAt(i) as AssetItemClassVO;
                    array = assetClass_.assetItemClassLocale;
                    if(assetClass_ != null && array != null && array.length >0)
                    {
                    assetClassD_ = array.getItemAt(0) as AssetItemClassLocale;

                    arrayContent.addItem(new Array(assetClass_.id,assetClassD_.name,assetClassD_.description,assetClassD_.locale,assetClass_.createdby,assetClass_.createdtime,assetClass_.lastmodifiedby,assetClass_.lastmodifiedtime));

                    }            
                }   


                    dg.dataProvider = arrayContent;
```

But after doing this, I am getting the column name as 1,2,3,4,5 ...8.
But I want to set theColumn name as ID,Name,Description,Locale,CreatedBy,CreatedTime,LastModifiedBy,LastModifiedTime.

How do i do it?

Please help.

Comment: Why is this tagged c#? And looks like you need to change arrayContent.addItem(new Array... to arrayContent.addItem(new Object(...))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but here's an example of DataGrid data binding.  Hope it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application initialize="init()"
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var employees:ArrayCollection;

            private function init():void
            {
                employees = new ArrayCollection();
                employees.addItem({name: "Oscar", phone: "907.123.4567", email: "oscar@isacat.net"});
                employees.addItem({name: "Nimrod", phone: "907.876.5342", email: "nimrod@isacat.net"});
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:DataGrid id="dg" color="0x323232" width="100%" rowCount="3" dataProvider="{employees}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="phone" headerText="Phone"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="email" headerText="Email"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>  
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks echo! . I did little tweaks, finally it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the data on arraycollection, maybe you can check my code, i create dynamic table on Datagrid

```
private function addDataGridParamColumn(tmp:String):void
{
    var dgColumn:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn(tmp);
    var arr:Array = dg.columns; 
    dg.headerRenderer = new ClassFactory(Label);

    switch(tmp)
    {
      case "Name":
        dgColumn.dataField = 'Name';
        dgColumn.width = 150;
        dgColumn.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(Label);
      break;
    }

    arr.push(dgColumn);
    dg.columns = arr;
}
```

you can call function addDataGridParamColumn(this is the name header) and add case for looping